# How to bind dynamic object in .NET Core 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Just read a few SO threads about this but nothing seems to work.

Simply put I am posting a object as follows:

```
{
    "Name" : "TestName",
    "Other" : { "item":"test" }
}
```

Controller action looks like this controller is `ApiController`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post(string name, dynamic other)
{}
```

Cannot seem to have other bind as dynamic object. Breakpoint shows there is a `ValueKind` in other. Still can't seem to do `Other.item` to read item value.

Must be missing something simple but not sure what.

**EDIT**

It seems everyone is suggesting to use a strongly typed object.

The issue is that I don't know the values until they are entered.  Take the following for example:

```
{
"ItemCount":1,
items:[{
"name":"item",
"price":5
}]
}
```

This is for a templating system.  The workings of the template system are not important here but what is important is the user can decide the field names like ItemCount can be whatever name they want same with the items Array they can call it things/cart whatever.

I believe in this case it has to be a dynamic object.  Open to suggestions however.

Comment: But why though? Why not just `Dictionary<string,string> other`? Or if you know the thing will have an `.item` property, define a new class / struct.

Comment: I don't know the thing.  would Dictionary<string,string> only work for top level?  What about if I have inner objects?

Comment: IMHO you should either know exactly what data you expect, and therefore should define a class to represent that data (`class Data{string Name; OtherData Other;} class OtherData{string Item;}` etc). Or you know nothing, because you're just passing the data blindly somewhere else, in which case you could probably bind `JObject`?

Comment: This is a situation where object is not know.  i would normally create strongly typed objects as you said but sometimes depending on complexity of a large system you simply cannot.  Anyway odd thing replaced System.Text.Json with Newtonsoft and all seems to work as expected.  Maybe System.Text.Json not supporting proper binding.

Comment: `dynamic` is not a _type_. It's a keyword to tell the compiler to defer any binding until runtime. There's no concept of a "dynamic" type in ASP.NET web API. How would users of the API know what type to pass in?

Comment: @DStanley Aware of that :).  And documentation would tell them.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can make  it  is using JObject or JArray

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post(JObject model)
{
var name = model.SelectToken("Name").ToString();
.... and so on
}
```

But I really can not even imagine why anybody will need to use dynamic object in controller acton. This is why it is not supported.